# Why use softmax as opposed to standard normalization?

Tags: math, neural-network, softmax

In the output layer of a neural network, it is typical to use the softmax function to approximate a probability distribution:

[image]

This is expensive to compute because of the exponents. Why not simply perform a Z transform so that all outputs are positive, and then normalise just by dividing all outputs by the sum of all outputs?

Comment: The function is not expensive to compute because of the exponents, but because you need to compute every qj. The exponentiation is cheap compared to the total amount of computation needed.

Comment: What kind of Z transform are you talking about? The signal processing meaning of the term doesn't fit here, and replacing the values with their z-score yields negative output if input is below the mean.

Comment: See also: [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/419751/25741)

Answer (score 199, accepted):

There is one nice attribute of Softmax as compared with standard normalisation.

It react to low stimulation (think blurry image) of your neural net with rather uniform distribution and to high stimulation (ie. large numbers, think crisp image) with probabilities close to 0 and 1.

While standard normalisation does not care as long as the proportion are the same.

Have a look what happens when soft max has 10 times larger input, ie your neural net got a crisp image and a lot of neurones got activated

```
>>> softmax([1,2])              # blurry image of a ferret
[0.26894142,      0.73105858])  #     it is a cat perhaps !?
>>> softmax([10,20])            # crisp image of a cat
[0.0000453978687, 0.999954602]) #     it is definitely a CAT !
```

And then compare it with standard normalisation

```
>>> std_norm([1,2])                      # blurry image of a ferret
[0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666] #     it is a cat perhaps !?
>>> std_norm([10,20])                    # crisp image of a cat
[0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666] #     it is a cat perhaps !?
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer is the most voted. Why does [1,2] correspond to a blurry image while [10,20] correspond to a sharper image? This is simply a matter of scaling and both cases are essentially the same. If anything, this should seem to support standard normalization, which correctly considers the two cases equivalent.

Comment: When the values are already guaranteed to be in [0, 1], is there still any advantage of taking softmax instead of simply dividing by the sum?

Comment: @MartinThoma the values were arbitrary just to help follow the math, if your network has some normalisation (eg. batch norm) and output values in [0,1] then by using  softmax you can still tell when your outputs get excited. Consider [0.001, 0.002] (0.49975, 0.50025) vs [0.5, 1.0] (0.37, 0.62)

Comment: @user118967, Good question, there are number of reasons why a network should output larger numbers when it is more sure. I will try to find a simple answer later.  For the time being think how convolution filters + relu manifest feature detection with large activations, how max pooling helps preserve largest  activation, and most importantly SGD + cross-entropy  loss (softmax) teaches network to output larger activation when it is more sure (as softmax encourage that).

Comment: Wouldn't the crisp image score `[1,20]`, though?

Comment: @herbert, depends on the picture it self, the numbers are made up. Have you seen this one: https://smartcdn.prod.postmedia.digital/canoe/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/dui.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1128&type=webp

Comment: @PiotrCzapla the smartcdn link seems to be broken

Comment: @user118967 I guess it would make more sense if the example was more realistic, i.e. [1,2] and [10,20] representing the feature map (output of CNN layers) of an image. Then you'd expect more confidence when the difference is larger.

Answer (score 133):

I've had this question for months. It seems like we just cleverly guessed the softmax as an output function and then interpret the input to the softmax as log-probabilities. As you said, why not simply normalize all outputs by dividing by their sum? I found the answer in the [Deep Learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville (2016) in section 6.2.2.

Let's say our last hidden layer gives us z as an activation. Then the softmax is defined as

[image]

## Very Short Explanation

The exp in the softmax function roughly cancels out the log in the cross-entropy loss causing the loss to be roughly linear in z_i. This leads to a roughly constant gradient, when the model is wrong, allowing it to correct itself quickly. Thus, a wrong saturated softmax does not cause a vanishing gradient.

## Short Explanation

The most popular method to train a neural network is Maximum Likelihood Estimation. We estimate the parameters theta in a way that maximizes the likelihood of the training data (of size m). Because the likelihood of the whole training dataset is a product of the likelihoods of each sample, it is easier to maximize the **log-likelihood** of the dataset and thus the sum of the log-likelihood of each sample indexed by k:

[image]

Now, we only focus on the softmax here with z already given, so we can replace

[image]

with i being the correct class of the kth sample. Now, we see that when we take the logarithm of the softmax, to calculate the sample's log-likelihood, we get:

[image]

, which for large differences in z roughly approximates to

[image]

First, we see the linear component z_i here. Secondly, we can examine the behavior of max(z) for two cases:

1. If the model is correct, then max(z) will be z_i. Thus, the log-likelihood asymptotes zero (i.e. a likelihood of 1) with a growing difference between z_i and the other entries in z.
2. If the model is incorrect, then max(z) will be some other z_j > z_i. So, the addition of z_i does not fully cancel out -z_j and the log-likelihood is roughly (z_i - z_j). This clearly tells the model what to do to increase the log-likelihood: increase z_i and decrease z_j.

We see that the overall log-likelihood will be dominated by samples, where the model is incorrect. Also, even if the model is really incorrect, which leads to a saturated softmax, the loss function does not saturate. It is approximately linear in z_j, meaning that we have a roughly constant gradient. This allows the model to correct itself quickly. Note that this is not the case for the Mean Squared Error for example.

## Long Explanation

If the softmax still seems like an arbitrary choice to you, you can take a look at the justification for using the sigmoid in logistic regression:

[Why sigmoid function instead of anything else?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/318209/118955)

The softmax is the generalization of the sigmoid for multi-class problems justified analogously.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain this statement and how were you able to approximate? ", which for large differences in z roughly approximates to"

Comment: @Londonguy. Let M = max(z_j), then z_i - log∑exp(z_j) = z_i - log∑exp(M + z_j - M) = z_i - log∑(exp(M) * exp(z_j - M)) = z_i - M + log∑exp(z_j - M). When there are large differences in z, we can approximate exp(z_j - M) ≈ 0 for z_j ≠ M. So z_i - M + log∑exp(z_j - M) ≈ z_i - M + log(exp(M - M)) = z_i - M

Answer (score 58):

I have found the explanation here to be very good: [CS231n: Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual Recognition.](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax)

On the surface the softmax algorithm seems to be a simple non-linear (we are spreading the data with exponential) normalization. However, there is more than that.

Specifically there are a couple different views ([same link as above](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax)):

1. Information Theory - from the perspective of information theory the softmax function can be seen as trying to minimize the cross-entropy between the predictions and the truth.
2. Probabilistic View - from this perspective we are in fact looking at the log-probabilities, thus when we perform exponentiation we end up with the raw probabilities. In this case the softmax equation find the MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimate)

In summary, even though the softmax equation seems like it could be arbitrary it is NOT. It is actually a rather principled way of normalizing the classifications to minimize cross-entropy/negative likelihood between predictions and the truth.

Comment: To add to previous comments, the derivative of the softmax function is just softmax(1-softmax)

Comment: I get the reasons for using Cross-Entropy Loss, but how does that relate to the softmax? You said "the softmax function can be seen as trying to minimize the cross-entropy between the predictions and the truth". Suppose, I would use standard / linear normalization, but still use the Cross-Entropy Loss. Then I would also try to minimize the Cross-Entropy. So how is the softmax linked to the Cross-Entropy **except** for the numerical benefits?

Comment: As for the probabilistic view: what is the motivation for looking at log probabilities? The reasoning seems to be a bit like "We use e^x in the softmax, because we interpret x as log-probabilties". With the same reasoning we could say, we use e^e^e^x in the softmax, because we interpret x as log-log-log-probabilities (Exaggerating here, of course). I get the numerical benefits of softmax, but what is the theoretical motivation for using it?

Comment: @KilianBatzner If a neuron's output is a log probability, then the summation of many neurons' outputs is a multiplication of their probabilities. That's more commonly useful than a sum of probabilities.

Comment: @KilianBatzner If your features come from different Gaussian clusters (on cluster per class) then you can derive a perfect classifier (logistic regression). There are some additional conditions, but essentially you can justify/derive softmax and logits with the assumption that you want to seperate gaussian clusters.

Answer (score 18):

The values of `q_i` are unbounded scores, sometimes interpreted as log-likelihoods. Under this interpretation, in order to recover the raw probability values, you must exponentiate them.

One reason that statistical algorithms often use log-likelihood loss functions is that they are more numerically stable: a product of probabilities may be represented be a very small floating point number. Using a log-likelihood loss function, a product of probabilities becomes a sum.

Another reason is that log-likelihoods occur naturally when deriving estimators for random variables that are assumed to be drawn from multivariate Gaussian distributions. See for example the Maximum Likelihood (ML) estimator and the way it is connected to least squares.

Comment: q_i don't implicitly represent log-likelihoods. it is only when we use the softmax that we explicitly assume they do.

Answer (score 9):

We are looking at a multiclass classification problem. That is, the predicted variable `y` can take one of `k` categories, where `k > 2`. In probability theory, this is usually modelled by a multinomial distribution. Multinomial distribution is a member of exponential family distributions. We can reconstruct the probability `P(k=?|x)` using properties of exponential family distributions, it coincides with the softmax formula.

If you believe the problem can be modelled by another distribution, other than multinomial, then you could reach a conclusion that is different from softmax.

For further information and a formal derivation please refer to [CS229 lecture notes (9.3 Softmax Regression)](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf).

Additionally, a useful trick usually performs to softmax is: *softmax(x) = softmax(x+c)*, softmax is invariant to constant offsets in the input.

[image: enter image description herse]

Comment: How does it work as an activation function, as it is returning the same value for 'x' and 'x+c'?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `softmax` is not an activation function. Activation function is an element-wise operation -- giving a tensor element-wisely performing a non-linear operation to produce another tensor. But `softmax` is a vector operation, it produce you a normalised vector, there's inner dependencies between each element.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Piotr Czapla answer, the greater the input values, the greater the probability for the maximum input, for same proportion and compared to the other inputs:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> The choice of the softmax function seems **somehow arbitrary** as there are many other possible normalizing functions. It is thus unclear why the log-softmax loss would perform better than other loss alternatives.

From "**An Exploration of Softmax Alternatives Belonging to the Spherical Loss Family**" https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05042

The authors explored some other functions among which are Taylor expansion of `exp` and so called spherical softmax and found out that sometimes they might perform better than usual `softmax`.

Answer (score 8):

I think one of the reasons can be to deal with the negative numbers and division by zero, since exp(x) will always be positive and greater than zero.

For example for `a = [-2, -1, 1, 2]` the sum will be 0, we can use softmax to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Normally you would subtract the minimum then divide by the max/sum. In your case that would make `[0, 1, 3, 4]` then dividing.

Comment: @ubershmekel This runs into the problem that the class with the smallest score will always be assigned a probability of 0.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we change the softmax function so the output activations are given by
[image]

where `c` is a positive constant. Note that `c=1` corresponds to the standard softmax function. But if we use a different value of `c` we get a different function, which is nonetheless qualitatively rather similar to the softmax. In particular, show that the output activations form a probability distribution, just as for the usual softmax. Suppose we allow `c` to become large, i.e., `c→∞`. What is the limiting value for the output activations `a^L_j`? After solving this problem it should be clear to you why we think of the `c=1` function as a "softened" version of the maximum function. This is the origin of the term "softmax". You can follow the details from [this source](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html) (equation 83).

Comment: For me, the idea of "softened" version of the maximum function is the best simple way to justify the use of softmax.

Answer (score 1):

While it indeed somewhat [arbitrary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296471/why-e-in-softmax/509362#509362), the softmax has desirable properties such as:

- being easily diferentiable (`df/dx = f*(1-f)`)
- when used as the output layer for a classification task, the in-fed scores are interpretable as [log-odds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66804099/9067615)