# Logistic Regression to support multiple classes directly

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

My Understanding is Softmax Regression is generalization of Logistic Regression to support multiple classes .

Softmax Regression model first computes a score for each class then estimates the probability of each class by applying the softmax function  to the scores.

Each class has its own dedicated parameter vector

**My question :** Why can't we use Logistic Regression to classify to multiple classes in a much simpler way like if probability is 0 to 0.3 then Class A ; 0.3 to 0.6 then Class B : 0.6 to 0.9 then Class C etc.

Why separate coefficient vector is always needed ?

I'm new to ML . Not sure if this question is due to lack of any fundamental concept understanding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, in terms of terminology, I'd say a more established terminology is [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression).

Softmax function is a natural choice for computing probabilities because it [corresponds to MLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187507/why-use-softmax-as-opposed-to-standard-normalization). [Cross-entropy loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) has a probabilistic interpretation as well - that's the "distance" between two distributions (output and target).
What you suggest is to discriminate classes in an artificial way - output a binary distribution and somehow compare it to a multi-class distribution. In theory, it is possible and may work, but surely has drawbacks. For example, it is harder to train.

Suppose the output is `0.2` (i.e. class A) and the ground truth is class B. You'd like to tell the network to shift towards a higher value. Next time, the output is `0.7` - the network actually learned and moved in the right direction, but you punish it again. In fact, there are unstable points (`0.3` and `0.6` in your example) that the network need time to learn as critical ones. Two values - `0.2999999` and `0.3000001` are almost indistinguishable for the network, but they determine if the result is correct or not.

In general, output as a probability distribution is always better than direct discrimination, because it gives more information.