# how softmax differs from finding the average of each value from total value?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

I have been trying to understand the softmax, and came up with below simple example.

```
def simpleSoftmax(allValues):
    return np.exp(allValues) / np.sum(np.exp(allValues), axis=0)
```

Invoke

```
simpleSoftmax([3,2,4])
array([ 0.24472847,  0.09003057,  0.66524096])
```

In this case 0.66 has higher probability. Understood.

Now, this shall be done like

```
(3/9)*100 = 33.33
(2/9)*100 =  22.22
(4/9)*100 = 44.44
```

Now if we see 44.44 takes higher value, and which results same as softmax.

I am sure there is something interesting behind this softmax with respect to legacy averaging. However i dont understand what is that going to make difference between these two ways?.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187507/why-use-softmax-as-opposed-to-standard-normalization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use softmax as opposed to standard normalization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187507/why-use-softmax-as-opposed-to-standard-normalization)